# How to organize large scale Extjs application in Sencha Architect?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I am working on an enterprise level application which consists of number of views, models, stores, controllers. It was very easy when there were less number of these. But now they are being added as a part of development. Sencha architect is not providing any kind of Project explorer where we can organize folders and files like Eclipse, NetBeans. I want to create folders in views, modules, stores and controllers and to segregate files accordingly. like this:

[image]

Comment: you can create folders under view/store/model/controller. But you need to include the folder name in the namespace.